# Getting error for undefined index in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have below code in my `header.php`, values of `$menu` is coming from '`my_controller.php` & database query has been defined in `menu_model.php`.

**Error Message**

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined Index: menu_name
Filename: Header.php
Line number: 187
Backtrace:
    File: ////Header.php
    Line: 187
    Function: _error_handler

    File: ////my_controller.php
    Line: 32
    Function: view
```

**menu_model.php**

```
public function get_main_menu()
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('menu');
    $this->db->order_by("menu_id", "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

**my_controller.php**

```
protected function loadHeader($title = 'Home')
{       
    $menu['menu'] = $this->menu_model->get_main_menu()->result_array();
    //var_dump($menu['menu']); ***This shows data which is mentioned below
    $data['menu'] = $menu;
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);  ***This is line 32
}
```

**header.php**

```
<?php foreach ((array_values($menu)) as $mega_menu): ?> 
    <li class="mega-menu">
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL.('/category/'.$mega_menu['menu_id'].'/'); ?>">
    <div><?php echo $mega_menu['menu_name']?></div>
    </a> ***This is line 187
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**var_dump($menu)**

```
array(1) { ["menu"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(4) { ["menu_id"]=> string(1) "1"
["menu_name"]=> string(14) "Start Business" ["menu_desc"]=> string(34) "DSC,
DPIN Initiation etc. services" ["breadcrumb_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(4)
{ ["menu_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["menu_name"]=> string(12) "Intellectual" ["menu_desc"]=>
string(35) "Trademark and Copyright Filing etc." ["breadcrumb_id"]=> string(1) "0" }
[2]=> array(4) { ["menu_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["menu_name"]=> string(8) "Personal"
["menu_desc"]=> string(47) "Wills, Rent Agreements, General Affidavits etc."
["breadcrumb_id"]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(4) { ["menu_id"]=> string(1) "4"
["menu_name"]=> string(9) "Contracts" ["menu_desc"]=> string(32) "General
Business Agreements etc." ["breadcrumb_id"]=> string(1) "0" } } }
```

Can somebody help me finding the error?

Comment: post your complete error message

Comment: Usually undefined index errors are also accompanied by a line number, and more to the error. Can you post the entire error, along with some line numbers?

Comment: Semantics; Undefined Index is a Notice

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have added the error message.

Comment: change this to `<?php foreach ((array_values($menu)) as $mega_menu): ?> ` this `<?php foreach ($menu as $mega_menu): ?>`

Comment: Just a tip for file and class naming https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming also `MY_Controller.php` not `my_controller.php` same for the `class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {}`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam That isn't working, same error.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yeah that was taken care of, it's because I've manually written it I made a mistake in naming convention.

Comment: that's not error fix. its just tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some change your `my_controller.php`. Can `$data['menu'] = $menu['menu'];` instead of `$data['menu'] = $menu;`

```
protected function loadHeader($title = 'Home')
{       
    $menu['menu'] = $this->menu_model->get_main_menu()->result_array();
    //var_dump($menu['menu']); ***This shows data which is mentioned below
    $data['menu'] = $menu['menu'];
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);  ***This is line 32
}
```

Comment: That was so simple. I completed missed it, thanks.:)

Comment: making only this changes is not complete solution.There is also error in header.php.

Answer (score 1):

First save `menu_model.php` as `Menu_model.php` with following Code

```
public function get_main_menu()
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('menu');
    $this->db->order_by("menu_id", "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Save `my_controller.php` as `My_controller.php` with following code.

```
protected function loadHeader($title = 'Home')
{       
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('menu_model');
    $menu= $this->menu_model->get_main_menu()->result_array();
    $data['menu'] = $menu;
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
}
```

And at your view make the following code:

```
<?php foreach($menu as $mega_menu): ?> 
    <li class="mega-menu">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('category/'.$mega_menu['menu_id']); ?>">
    <div><?php echo $mega_menu['menu_name'];?></div>
    </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```